# Como filtrar una Tabla dinamica con VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy tratandode filtrar una tabla dinamica con VBA Excel cuando no agrela tabla al modelo de datos, no tengo problemas, el problema empieza cuando lo agrego al modelo de datos, lo hago por que necesito hacer un recuento de un campo, usa la opcion de grabar macro y me genero el siguiente codigo:

```
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields( _
    "[Range].[Familia].[Familia]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Range].[Familia].&[ALAMBRE RECOCIDO]")
```

Cuando hago una prueba paso a paso funciona perfecto, si pongo otro nombre funciona sin problemas, pero como es un proceso dinamco, necesito cambiar ese nombre y lo tomo de otra hoja y cuando lo mando al script me genera un error, el script que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields( _
    "[Range].[Familia].[Familia]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Range].[Familia].&[' & Familia & ']")
```

Donde Familia es la variable para cambiar el filtro y este es el error que me genera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que mas hacer si alguien sabe como hacer esto agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambiando `'` por `"`, porque en

```
"[Range].[Familia].&[' & Familia & ']"
```

no estás evaluando la variable `Familia` sino que se está tomando como parte del texto. Quedaría:

```
"[Range].[Familia].&[" & Familia & "]"
```

Comment: Hola @Pollo, gracias por tu respuesta, pero ahora presento otro problema, y es que cuando mando la variable o un vector con varios filtros si alguno no existe me da un error, como hago para validar si existe o no en la lista de los filtros??

Comment: Me alegro que te funcionara!! Para tu otro problema, podés buscar si existe en `PivotField.PivotItems` ... Sin embargo, otro problema = otra pregunta ... Plantealo generando una nueva pregunta en el sitio y quien tenga ganas y pueda te va a responder